# Sql nao retorna nome de coluna

Tags: sql, query

Tenho duas tabelas uma `TEAM` outra `MATCH_DETAILS`. A tabela `TEAM` tem a coluna `id` e é chave primaria. Fiz duas relaçoes da tabela `TEAM` para `MATCH_DETAILS`. Na `MATCH_DETAILS` assumiu como chave estrangeira `team_id` e `team_id1`.

Com a seguinte *query*:

```
SELECT  
  team_name, team_id1, Umpire_name, 
  playermatch_name, score_id
FROM 
  Match_details m, Team t, 
  Umpire u, player_match p, Score s
WHERE m.TEAM_TEAM_ID = t.TEAM_ID 
  and m.TEAM_TEAM_ID1 =  m.TEAM_TEAM_ID1 
  and m.UMPIRE_UMPIRE_ID = u.UMPIRE_ID 
  and p.Match_details_MATCH_ID = m.match_id 
  and s.Match_details_MATCH_ID = m.match_id;
```

Retorna o seguinte:

[image: printscreen do header da tabela tag]

A euipa Chelsea tem como `id` numero 1  o `id` numero 2 na coluna `team_id1` corresponde a euipa `liverpool`. aquilo que pretendo é aparecer `Liverpool` e não o `id` que corresponde.

Answer (score 0):

Em primeiro lugar, eu sugeria utilizar junções explícitas ao invés de junções implícitas (ANSI-92). Apesar de não haver diferenças de performance, a "nova" sintaxe é bastante mais legível quando existem muitas tabelas envolvidas (como é o seu caso).

Dito isto, a sua query pode ser re-escrita da seguinte forma.

```
SELECT  T1.TEAM_NAME,
        T2.TEAM_NAME, 
        U.Umpire_name, 
        playermatch_name,
        score_id
  FROM Match_details m_d, 
 INNER JOIN Team T1  -- Detalhes da primeira equipa
    ON T1.TEAM_ID = m_d.TEAM_ID
 INNER JOIN Team T2  -- Detalhes da segunda equipa
    ON T2.TEAM_ID = m_d.TEAM_ID1
 INNER JOIN Umpire U
    ON U.UMPIRE_ID = m_d.UMPIRE_UMPIRE_ID
 INNER JOIN player_match P
    ON P.Match_details_MATCH_ID = m_d.match_id 
 INNER JOIN Score S
    ON S.Match_details_MATCH_ID = m_d.match_id
```

Note a dupla junção na tabela TEAM: Uma para a primeira equipa (no seu exemplo Chelsea) e outra para a segunda equipa (Liverpool). Para mostrar o nome da segunda equipa no resultado, basta selecionar o nome da tabela respective (T2) ao invés do ID.

Comment: experimentei sua sugerencia e nao funcionou apresenta o seguinte erro:ORA-00933: comando SQL não foi terminado correctamente
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: @DianaMadeira, editei a resposta. Faltava incluir "JOIN" em duas das junções